# TcpClient exceptions when calling EndReceive and BeginReceive

Tags: c#, .net, tcplistener

I'm trying to implement wrapper class which will simply connect to TCP server and wait for data. Once data submitted from server - I will receive this data and pass it onto subscribers of my class.

All this works. Now I want to add external functionality to "reset" this class on a timer (force reconnect every so often) to keep connection alive. My idea is that `Init` method can be called as many times as needed to get socket reset. However, I do get various exceptions with this.

**Class code:**

```
namespace Ditat.GateControl.Service.InputListener
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Text;

    public class BaseTCPSocketListener : IInputListener
    {
        #region Events/Properties

        public event EventHandler<Exception> OnError;

        public event EventHandler<string> OnDataReceived;

        private string host;

        private int port;

        private int delayToClearBufferSeconds = 5;

        private TcpClient client;

        private readonly byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        /// <summary>
        /// Will accumulate data as it's received
        /// </summary>
        private string DataBuffer { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Store time of last data receipt. Need this in order to purge data after delay
        /// </summary>
        private DateTime LastDataReceivedOn { get; set; }

        #endregion

        public BaseTCPSocketListener()
        {
            // Preset all entries
            this.LastDataReceivedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
            this.DataBuffer = string.Empty;

        }

        public void Init(string config)
        {
            // Parse info
            var bits = config.Split(new[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            this.host = bits[0];
            var hostBytes = this.host.Split(new[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var hostIp = new IPAddress(new[] { byte.Parse(hostBytes[0]), byte.Parse(hostBytes[1]), byte.Parse(hostBytes[2]), byte.Parse(hostBytes[3]) });
            this.port = int.Parse(bits[1]);
            this.delayToClearBufferSeconds = int.Parse(bits[2]);

            // Close open client
            if (this.client?.Client != null)
            {
                this.client.Client.Disconnect(true);
                this.client = null;
            }

            // Connect to client
            this.client = new TcpClient();
            if (!this.client.ConnectAsync(hostIp, this.port).Wait(2500))
                throw new Exception($"Failed to connect to {this.host}:{this.port} in allotted time");

            this.EstablishReceiver();
        }

        protected void DataReceived(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            // End the data receiving that the socket has done and get the number of bytes read.
            var bytesCount = 0;
            try
            {
                bytesCount = this.client.Client.EndReceive(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.RaiseOnErrorToClient(new Exception(nameof(this.DataReceived)));
                this.RaiseOnErrorToClient(ex);
            }

            // No data received, establish receiver and return
            if (bytesCount == 0)
            {
                this.EstablishReceiver();
                return;
            }

            // Convert the data we have to a string.
            this.DataBuffer += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(this.buffer, 0, bytesCount);

            // Record last time data received
            this.LastDataReceivedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
            this.RaiseOnDataReceivedToClient(this.DataBuffer);

            this.DataBuffer = string.Empty;
            this.EstablishReceiver();
        }

        private void EstablishReceiver()
        {
            try
            {
                // Set up again to get the next chunk of data.
                this.client.Client.BeginReceive(this.buffer, 0, this.buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, this.DataReceived, this.buffer);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.RaiseOnErrorToClient(new Exception(nameof(this.EstablishReceiver)));
                this.RaiseOnErrorToClient(ex);
            }
        }

        private void RaiseOnErrorToClient(Exception ex)
        {
            if (this.OnError == null) return;

            foreach (Delegate d in this.OnError.GetInvocationList())
            {
                var syncer = d.Target as ISynchronizeInvoke;
                if (syncer == null)
                {
                    d.DynamicInvoke(this, ex);
                }
                else
                {
                    syncer.BeginInvoke(d, new object[] { this, ex });
                }
            }
        }

        private void RaiseOnDataReceivedToClient(string data)
        {
            if (this.OnDataReceived == null) return;

            foreach (Delegate d in this.OnDataReceived.GetInvocationList())
            {
                var syncer = d.Target as ISynchronizeInvoke;
                if (syncer == null)
                {
                    d.DynamicInvoke(this, data);
                }
                else
                {
                    syncer.BeginInvoke(d, new object[] { this, data });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Client code (under button click on form)**

```
private void ListenBaseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.bsl == null)
            {
                this.bsl = new BaseTCPSocketListener();
                this.bsl.OnDataReceived += delegate (object o, string s)
                {
                    this.DataTextBox.Text += $"Base: {DateTime.Now} - {s}" + Environment.NewLine;
                };

                this.bsl.OnError += delegate (object o, Exception x)
                {
                    this.DataTextBox.Text += $"Base TCP receiver error: {DateTime.Now} - {x.Message}" + Environment.NewLine;
                };
            }

            try
            {
                this.bsl.Init("192.168.33.70|10001|10");
                this.DataTextBox.Text += "BEGIN RECEIVING BSL data --------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                this.DataTextBox.Text += $"ERROR CONNECTING TO BSL ------------{exception.Message}" + Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }
```

Exceptions I get. First exception when button clicked 2nd time in from handler in `DataReceived`

> The IAsyncResult object was not returned from the corresponding
>   asynchronous method on this class.

On following clicks I get exception from handler in `EstablishReceiver`

> A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is
>   not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto
>   call) no address was supplied

How do I properly ensure socket closed and re-opened?

Comment: First exception is caused by a basic threading race bug, the code changes the `client` variable before the DataReceived event for the old client fires.  Look at the MSDN code example to see how you can use IAsyncResult.AsyncState to retrieve the correct socket.   Second exception is caused by calling BeginReceive even though DataReceived returned 0 bytes.  0 means that the socket is disconnected, so you want to quit.  Using Dispose() is better, catch the ODE with try/catch.  Having this kind of trouble is the basic reason Microsoft added the async/await pattern.

Comment: A warning. This code seems to be built based on the presumption that you'll be receiving *messages*. That's not the TCP abstraction. TCP connections deal in terms of a *stream of bytes* in both directions. This means that you cannot presume that any call to Receive is going to get one and exactly one complete "thing". As such, you cannot assume that what you've received is a *complete* UTF8 string. You may have a buffer that contains only *part* of a UTF 8 character at its end (and your next buffer will contain the remaining parts of that character)

Comment: If you want *messaging*, it's up to you to implement message framing yourself atop TCP or to move to a higher level protocol that already works in terms of messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The IAsyncResult object was not returned from the corresponding
>   asynchronous method on this class.

This is a well known problem that happens when data callback (`DataReceived()`) is called for previous socket. In this case you will call `Socket.EndReceive()` with incorrect instance of `IAsyncResult` which throws above exception.

[Asynchronous Client Socket Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example) contains possible workaround for this problem: store socket on which `BeginReceive()` was called in state object which is then passed to `DataReceived` callback:

**StateObject class**

```
public class StateObject
{
    public Socket Socket { get; set; }

    public byte[] Buffer { get; } = new byte[1024];

    public StateObject(Socket socket)
    {
        Socket = socket;
    }
}
```

**EstablishReceiver() method:**

```
private void EstablishReceiver()
{
    try
    {
        var state = new StateObject(client.Client);
        // Set up again to get the next chunk of data.
        this.client.Client.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, this.DataReceived, state);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.RaiseOnErrorToClient(new Exception(nameof(this.EstablishReceiver)));
        this.RaiseOnErrorToClient(ex);
    }
}
```

**DataReceived() method:**

```
protected void DataReceived(IAsyncResult result)
{
    var state = (StateObject) result.AsyncState;

    // End the data receiving that the socket has done and get the number of bytes read.
    var bytesCount = 0;

    try
    {
        SocketError errorCode;
        bytesCount = state.Socket.EndReceive(result, out errorCode);
        if (errorCode != SocketError.Success)
        {
            bytesCount = 0;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.RaiseOnErrorToClient(new Exception(nameof(this.DataReceived)));
        this.RaiseOnErrorToClient(ex);
    }

    if (bytesCount > 0)
    {
        // Convert the data we have to a string.
        this.DataBuffer += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.Buffer, 0, bytesCount);

        // Record last time data received
        this.LastDataReceivedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
        this.RaiseOnDataReceivedToClient(this.DataBuffer);

        this.DataBuffer = string.Empty;
        this.EstablishReceiver();
    }
}
```

> A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is
>   not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto
>   call) no address was supplied

Above `DataReceived()` method also contains the fix for the second exception. Exception is caused by calling `BeginReceive()` (from `EstablishReceiver()`) on disconnected socket. You should not call `BeginReceive()` on a socket if previous read brought 0 bytes.

Comment: Great answer! Make sure to get every line of code right, or you get in the situation like me where I kept hours searching for a single swap of listener and handler socket ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're closing the socket being held by the TcpClient, but not disposing the client itself.  Try the following:

```
// Close open client
this.client?.Close();   // Disposes and releases resources
this.client = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that DataReceived will be called when you close the client. You simply need to identify to the method that it should not do anything because you have deliberately ended the process. You could just add a bool:

```
    private bool ignoreCallback;
    public void Init(string config)
    {
        // Parse info
        var bits = config.Split(new[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        this.host = bits[0];
        var hostBytes = this.host.Split(new[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var hostIp = new IPAddress(new[] { byte.Parse(hostBytes[0]), byte.Parse(hostBytes[1]), byte.Parse(hostBytes[2]), byte.Parse(hostBytes[3]) });
        this.port = int.Parse(bits[1]);
        this.delayToClearBufferSeconds = int.Parse(bits[2]);

        // Close open client
        if (this.client?.Client != null)
        {
            ignoreCallback = true;
            this.client.Client.Disconnect(true);
            this.client = null;
        }

        // Connect to client
        this.client = new TcpClient();
        if (!this.client.ConnectAsync(hostIp, this.port).Wait(2500))
            throw new Exception($"Failed to connect to {this.host}:{this.port} in allotted time");

        this.EstablishReceiver();
    }

    protected void DataReceived(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        if (ignoreCallback)
        {
            ignoreCallback = false;
            return;
        }

        ...
```